# CRAZY issue with headset audio volume/quality and skype

Tags: audio, skype

So I have a cheap logitech oem headset with normal audio jack and for some reason whenever I have a skype call it goes nuts. I have to jiggle the cable around for the audio to sound normal. If I turn my head the audio can go off or too quiet to hear and I often have to sit in a static position once it works and try not to move, and even then it may go wonky and I need to move again.

So I hear you all scoffing and thinking "Oh your headset is broken" which is EXACTLY what I thought, so I tried playing some other audio through it, and it works fine. I can move my head around and move the cable and no problems. I have even tried running an audio file in the background while on skype and the skype call audio is going all over the place as I move, but the windows audio file playing is 100% flawless.

So how can 1 application somehow go ballistic when the cable/headset is moved, but another application is fine...

Never have I seen/heard this sort of thing before and the internets seem to draw up a blank. So it does not seem like a hardware issue as such, or if it is it only seems to effect Skype and not anything else.

Any ideas?

== Update ==
Have just tried with both ear pieces on and same thing happens, I tried playing some sample audio from windows and the audio plays fine in both ears, then tried skype audio service and both ear pieces seemed iffy.

Comment: Presumably its stereo and the issue occurs on both ears?

Comment: That is a very interesting question, I only have the left earpiece on, let me put both on at once, like I am some hacker from the 1990's and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I've helped a friend who had a somewhat similar issue. This worked for him:

1. Click Start button
2. Type mmsys.cpl﻿
3. Click the Communications tab
4. Select Do Nothing
5. Save

Perhaps this works for you as well.

Comment: Tried this, still no improvement :( you get a +1 though as I am sure this will help others.

Comment: Mh too bad. Is this option enabled in Skype's settings dialog settings?
Open  "Audio devices" and if "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels"  is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: I will give that a try, I think I already tried turning that off a while ago but will give it another go and get back to you.

Comment: Just had a skype call now, still same issue.